# magento 2 how to edit custom header in site which path i can edit

Tags: magento2, xml, header, paths

here is the code for custom header

```
<div class="message global demo">
        <div class="content">
            <p>This is demo store. No orders will be fulfilled.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i also tried in app/design but not found

which path to edit this content or any other way to edit this(RED color border content)
 [image]

Comment: Have you enabled template path hints?

Comment: no............................

Comment: is there any settings in changing header in main site (admin panel)

Answer (score 1):

The content actual path is : **Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml** . directly changing content in core files is not recommended way.  instead of that you can override those template file.

create layout file for override global notices

app/code/**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->


<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Notices" name="global_notices" template="Vendor_Module::html/notices.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create a template file to override content app/code/**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Notices
 */
?>
<?php if ($block->displayNoscriptNotice()): ?>
    <noscript>
        <div class="message global noscript">
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser.') ?></strong>
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('For the best experience on our site, be sure to turn on Javascript in your browser.') ?></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->displayNoLocalStorageNotice()): ?>
    <div class="notice global site local_storage" style="display: none;">
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Local Storage seems to be disabled in your browser.') ?></strong><br />
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('For the best experience on our site, be sure to turn on Local Storage in your browser.') ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
require(['jquery'], function(jQuery){

        // <![CDATA[
        (function($) {
            var test = 'test';
            try {
                localStorage.setItem(test, test);
                localStorage.removeItem(test);
            } catch(e) {
                $(".notice.global.site.local_storage").show();
            }
        })(jQuery);
        // ]]>

});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->displayDemoNotice()): ?>
    <div class="message global demo">
        <div class="content">
            <p><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('This is demo store. No orders will be fulfilled.') ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Change your content whatever you want in "message global demo"

Comment: superb it's working thanks

can i get your mail for future contact

Comment: The "best" way to do this would be to override the translation CSV file instead of editing the PHTML.

Comment: yes, you are right, if he want to change only content he can go with translation, but if we need to change styles and content he needs to override the template